# php pages restrictions, how to make it work

Tags: php

below is my admin pannel code

```
<?php
     session_start();
     if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
      header("Location: login.php");
}
     if (isset($_SESSION['username'])&& $_SESSION['status'])
{ 
    include('adminnav.php');
}
 ?>
```

and this is my usernav bar

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])&& $_SESSION['status'])
{
header("Location: login.php");
}

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])&& $_SESSION['status'])
{
    $_SESSION['status'];
header("Location: usernav.php");
}


?>
```

i have same interface for admin and user for login , when i log in to system with user profile the user can assess admin pages e.g. remove user etc, all i wanna know it how to restrict user page and admin so that user can access admin page.

Comment: Create groups based on users, put certain users in $var based groups, then show/hide (echo) buttons or links based on a user group

Comment: i just want user to be directed to his own pages and admin to his own...

Comment: if im logged in from user acc. i still can access admin pages

Comment: just want to restrict user to his own pages

Comment: +1 for @clearshot comment, beside that, you should exit() after header(location) and better add a 'else' condition with whatever you need/want to put in it

Comment: I guess you store your user-information foreach user in the database. So maybe you just add a column named like 'privileges' or something. Then if he's admin he can access adminpage and own page. if privileg is normal, user can just access his own page. What you think about?

Comment: $_SESSION['status'] , here i kept status 1 for user in db  and 2 for admin.

Comment: but it still wont work.... i need to put a chick in it but i dont how wht and how to

Comment: I think personally your setup is poor. I'd create a database table with Access Level - Username , obtain user's current login and search their Access Level on the database, then on an index.php page,  if($access == 'admin'){ include adminnav.php }elseif... etc, adminnav should have the menu for admins only, usernav should have html menu for users.